# Port forwarding with DNAT and SNAT without touching other packets

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a Linux gateway with iptables which does routing and port forwarding. I want the port forwarding to happen independent of the routing.

To port forward, I add this to the `nat` table:

```
iptables -t nat -A "$PRE" -p tcp -d $GW --dport $fromPort -j DNAT --to-destination $toHost:$toPort
iptables -t nat -A "$POST" -p tcp -d $toHost --dport $toPort -j SNAT --to $SRC
```

`$PRE` and `POST` are actually destination-specific chains that I jump to from the `PREROUTING` and `POSTROUTING` chains respectively so I can keep the iptables clean. `$SRC` is the IP address I'm SNATing to which is different from the gateway IP `$GW`.

The problem with this setup is that regular routed packets that were not DNATed but happen to go to the same `$toHost:$toPort` combo will also be SNATed.

I wish to avoid this. Any clever things I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple: you don't actually need to `SNAT` anything. By doing this, every packet will reach the target server appearing to come from your firewall, rather than from the originating client, which in most cases is not what you want.

With the `SNAT` rule out of the way, you don't have to worry about it matching other traffic.

Note: Your `FORWARD` rules will have to match against the real source IP and the internal destination IP, since the `FORWARD` chain is reached after the `DNAT` rules are applied.

**EDIT**

Given the requirement for `SNAT`: as long as you're happy with the way the `DNAT` rule is matching packets, then you can precede that with a `mangle` rule that marks those same packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -A <mangle chain> -p tcp -d $GW --dport $fromPort -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

Then all your `SNAT` rule has to do is match those marked packets:

```
iptables -t nat -A "$POST" -m mark --mark 0x1 -j SNAT --to $SRC
```

If you need to identify multiple, separate streams, you should be able to vary the mark in script along with `$SRC`.

Comment: Thanks, in general you're right but in this particular case I actually I do want to NAT ;-). The routing is for private subnets and the port NAT has to appear to come from within the private subnet.

Comment: Marking might server your purpose, then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Or I could combine the current SNAT rule with the mark right? Excellent, didn't know about marking!